# Fonction de 'en' dans un discours (voici comment nous agissons en Européens)

Tags: en

Du discours du president [Macron](https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=306171874945828) :

> Face à la guerre et à la violence inouïe déployée par la Russie contre
> l'Ukraine et son peuple, voici comment nous agissons en Européens.

Je ne comprends pas pourquoi 'en' est utilisé ici. Dans ce contexte, est-il un synonyme de 'comme' ou 'en tant que' ?

Comment: «Produire plus vite, produire mieux et produire ensemble, en Européen.» C’est ainsi que le commissaire Thierry Breton résume le programme européen pour l’industrie de la défense (Edip) qui a été adopté mardi par la Commission. [Le Figaro, 5 mars]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oui, *(agir/se comporter) en tant que* est bien le sens de *en* ici. *Agir en Européen* équivaut à *agir en tant qu'Européen* ou *agir comme un Européen se doit de le faire*.

> TLFi [**Agir**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/agir)
> − Se conduire, se comporter.
> [...]
> [Avec un compl. précisant la manière dont se comporte le suj.] **Agir en** + subst. inactualisé; **agir comme** + subst. actualisé par l'art. un ou par un pron. (tel, etc.) :
>   28. − *Vous ne pouvez donc vous résoudre à quitter le canton qui vous a vu naître ? − Tous mes amis ont disparu de cette terre : les hommes qui les ont chassés sont violens et cruels; ils parlent de liberté, mais ils **agissent en** tyrans : oh ! sans doute, je quitterois sans peine des lieux que je ne reconnois plus !...* Mme de Genlis, *Les Chevaliers du cygne*, t. 1, 1795, p. 196.
> [...]
>   30. *« ... cette petite-fille de Jean Croissy est la dernière personne au monde que vous puissiez épouser. Vous seriez donc très coupable de troubler son cœur et de laisser naître et grandir dans le vôtre une passion sans issue. Vous êtes un honnête homme. Votre présence chez moi le prouve. **Agissez en** honnête homme. »* P. Bourget, *Nos actes nous suivent*, 1926, p. 84.